# Convergence of an alternating infinite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

What does the following infinite series converge to ?

$\displaystyle \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } (-1)^k \left(\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{1}{k}\right)-k\right)$

It seems that the given series converges to a specific numerical value. It is possible to verify this with Mathematica and Wolfran Alpha.

I'm wondering, is there a closed form analytical solution to this infinite series?

Thanks.

Comment: I'll ask the generic question I often ask in this situation; why do you think a simple closed-form exists?

Comment: @integrand Mostly curious to find out if a closed form solution exists. It might be simple, or not.

Comment: Have a look at my second answer.

Comment: Please expand, in your question body, on why you think "it seems that the given series converges to a specific numerical value, or was it just a wild guess? In short, your post fails to include any context whatsoever, why you are inclined to say what seems to be the case?  What is the source of the question,  What have you personally tried (and don't just claim what you tried, show us what you tried in your question.

Comment: @amWhy It can be verified numerically with Mathematica and Wolfram Alpha. This question was initially asked on Quora. And the answer given here shows the same numerical value. Does this help?

Comment: No, because you asked for a freebie... someone do this for me, took no time to attempt anything on your own, nor have you cited the source in your post.  Furthermore, you give no indication of how this question is important to you, what you're currently studying, etc., so that answerers can tailor answers to the level of study and experience you have.

Answer (score 3):

$$S= \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } (-1)^k \left(\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{1}{k}\right)-k\right)=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } (-1)^k \left(\cot\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)-k\right)$$

Numerically the result is $0.253374555381592$ which is not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.

If you compute the first $p$ terms
$$S=\sum _{k=1}^{p} (-1)^k \left(\cot\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)-k\right)+\sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty } (-1)^k \left(\cot\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)-k\right)$$ by Taylor, we have
$$a_k=\cot\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)-k=-\frac{1}{3 k}-\frac{1}{45 k^3}-\frac{2}{945
   k^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^7}\right)$$ The summation
$$S_p=\sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty } (-1)^k a_k$$ is explicit in terms of  the Hurwitz-Lerch transcendent function and the Hurwitz zeta function. Expanding again
$$S_p=(-1)^p \left(\frac{1}{6 p}-\frac{1}{12 p^2}+\frac{1}{90 p^3}+\frac{1}{40
   p^4}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{p^5}\right)$$ Using $p=100$ gives
$$S \approx 0.253374555381544$$

**Edit**

Using the infinite series
$$\cot\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)-k=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{ 2^{2 n+1}  \left(B_{2 n+2}+B_{2 n+2}(1)\right)}{(2 n+2)!\,\,k^{2 n+1}}$$ we could have
$$S_p=\frac{\log (2)}{3}+\sum_{n=1}^p (-1)^n\frac{2  \left(2^{2 n}-1\right) \zeta (2 n+1) \left(B_{2 (n+1)}+B_{2n+2}(1)\right)}{(2n+2)!}$$ which converges quite fast. $S_{50}$ gives $50$ exact decimal figures
$$S_{50}=0.25337455538159208879429837870426655264941867607205$$

Comment: Interesting results. How or where can the infinite series involving Bernoulli numbers be found?

Comment: @GeorgePa1. They are so many ! Here, they are Bernoulli numbers and Bernoulli polynomials.

Comment: @GeorgePa1 https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cot/06/01/02/01/0003/